# Discrete Math On Induction and Proof of sequence $a_n=2^n+3^n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show that the terms of the sequence that satisfy $a_0=2, a_1=5, a_n=5a_{n−1}−6a_{n−2}$, for all $n\ge2$, are given by the formula $a_n=2^n+3^n$.

Not sure how to go about this problem. Can someone help? Thanks 
${}{}{}{}$

Comment: What did you try? Are you able to show that any of the facts about the sequence are true for the formula?

Comment: If I read the problem correctly, that isn't true: https://ideone.com/CU1zl0

Comment: @Alex the edit to your post removed the exponent on the $3$. It is too small an edit for someone else to do. Could you please put the exponent back there? Thanks! 
Shahar, it was true as originally stated, but your edit removed the exponent on the 3

Comment: Show that the terms of the sequence that satisfy a_{0} = 2, a_{1} = 5, a_{n} = 5a_{n-1} - 6a_{n-2} for all n≥2, are given by the formula a_{n} = 2^{n} + 3^{n}

Comment: Thats the correct format.

Comment: @user139388 Dang, sorry - I'm editing from my phone right now. StackExchange needs an iPhone app.

Comment: No problem Shahar. There is an android app, but frustratingly it crashes every time I go to a post :( @Alex, can you please modify the post (not just the comment) so that the exponent appears on the $n$? We can't do that. Thanks!

Comment: https://ideone.com/SFlvZ3 Alright works now (kind of, starts getting messed up when the numbers are too high).

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that :(

Comment: @user139388 You can make small edits(if necessary), by simply placing a group of {}{}{} within dollar signs, I am sure you can see why this works to boost the edit character count without making visible change.

Comment: @Display Name Gotcha, will remember the tip. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check the base case:
$$
  a_2
= 5a_1 - 6a_0
= 25 - 12
= 13
= 2^2 + 3^2.
$$
Now suppose that $a_k = 2^k + 3^k$ is true for all $k \leq n-1$. Then
\begin{align}
   a_{n}
&= 5a_{n-1} - 6a_{n-2} \\
&= 5(2^{n-1} + 3^{n-1}) - 6(2^{n-2} + 3^{n-2}) \\
&= 2^{n-2}(5\cdot 2 - 6) + 3^{n-2}(5\cdot 3 - 6)\\
&= 2^n + 3^n.
\end{align}

Comment: I think we can take base case $n = 0$. Also if you suppose that it's true for all $k \leq n$, then obviously it will be true for $a_n$ :P.

Comment: @Amateur thanks, meant that to be $n-1$ :)

Answer (score 0):

A proof that uses the supplied answer:

It is true for 1 and 2.
Given the first two terms,
all subsequent terms are
determined by the recurrence.

$\begin{array}\\
5(2^{n-1}+3^{n-1})-6(2^{n-2}+3^{n-2})
&=5\cdot2^{n-1}-6\cdot 2^{n-2}+5\cdot 3^{n-1}-6 \cdot 3^{n-2}\\
&=10\cdot2^{n-2}-6\cdot 2^{n-2}+15\cdot 3^{n-2}-6 \cdot 3^{n-2}\\
&=4\cdot2^{n-2}+9\cdot 3^{n-2}\\
&=2^{n}+ 3^{n}\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 0):

Solve the recurrence using generating functions. Define $A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$, write the recurrence as:
$$
a_{n + 2} = 5 a_{n + 1} - 6 a_n
$$
Multiply by $z^n$ and sum over $n \ge 0$; recognize:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n + 1} z^n &= \frac{A(z) - a_0}{z} \\
\sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n + 2} z^n &= \frac{A(z) - a_0 - a_1 z}{z^2}
\end{align}
and get:
$$
\frac{A(z) - 2 - 5 z}{z^2} = 5 \frac{A(z) - 2}{z} - 6 A(z)
$$
Solving for $A(z)$ gets:
$$
A(z) = \frac{2 - 5 z}{1 - 5 z + 6 z^2}
     = \frac{1}{1 - 3 z} + \frac{1}{1 - 2 z}
$$
This is just two geometric series:
$$
a_n = 3^n + 2^n
$$